# Submit form with dynamically changing action attribute

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm trying to send form with dynamically changing action url, but right after changing attribute the form doesn't submits.

Here is simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/THZHL/1/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <form name="b" action="{{url}}" methood="post" ng-controller="formCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-click="set()">1. set url</button>
        <button type="submit">2. Send</button>
        {{url}}
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("formCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.set = function(){
            $scope.url = "/abc";
        }
    });
</script>
```

I don't understand why it happens in that way.

Comment: Even I don't know why this is happening but why don't you do it like this: add a `onsubmit="some_function()"` to the form and then you can send it to wherever you want to with this function and just add `return false;` to this function in the end.

Comment: You wouldnt really "submit" a Form with angular. Its not a nice pattern since it implies a compelte new page-refresh and thus your app would need to be completely rebuilded everytime. Angular is more for Single-Page-Applications, where you get your data dynamically with AJAX-Requests (or websockets) and use it to change your model (which then again changes your view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
`$scope.url` should be set with any non-empty value. Like there:

http://jsfiddle.net/THZHL/2/

```
app.controller("formCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.url = "/def";

    $scope.set = function(){
        $scope.url = "/abc";

    }
});
```