# POST request action form dynamic url angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am posting a file to the backend using an iframe to avoid a full page load. The action needs to post to a dynamic location based on the users's choice. i.e. depending on what element the user clicks on a different id will be given, which will then change the location of the action of the POST request.  When I hard code in the url it works - i.e. `www.test.com/1`, however when I change the action url dynamically using angular it is not working, although I can see the correct url when I inspect the element, the POST request is not happening. I am using `angular version 1.2.1`.

Please see my code below

```
<iframe id="uploadTrg" name="uploadTrg" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

<form id="myForm" action="{{actionUrl}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadTrg">
   File: <input type="file" name="cv">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn"/>
</form>

<div class="role-list" ng-repeat="(key, val) in obj">
    <div ng-repeat="subValue in val track by $index">
       <p class="role" ng-click="getId(subValue.id)">{{subValue.public_name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.getId = function(id) {
    $scope.actionUrl = 'http://www.test.com/' + id;
}
```

Comment: try to add Http to the url :"http:// www.test.com/"+ id;

Comment: apologies, the url is all good, that is just an example

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.getId = function(id) {
    document.myForm.action = 'www.test.com/' + id;
}
```

"myForm" is the name of the form `<form name="myForm>`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

It is necessary to add the $scope.actionUrl before the function for this to work.

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079054/submit-form-with-dynamically-changing-action-attribute).

```
$scope.actionUrl = '/';

$scope.getApplicationId = function(applicationId) {
    $scope.actionUrl = 'http://www.test.com/' + id;
}
```